# Javascript form onsubmit is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

Why does the following code not cause foo() to be called?

```
<script>
    function foo(){
        alert("hi"); 
        return false;
    }; 

    var myForm=document.createElement('FORM'); 
    myForm.method='POST'; 
    myForm.action="http://www.example.com/test.php"; 
    myForm.id="myForm"; 

    myForm.onsubmit="return foo()";

    document.body.appendChild(myForm); 

    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
</script>
```

I tried `myForm.onsubmit="(e)=>{alert("hi"); e.preventDefault()}";` as well, also not working.

Comment: onsubmit should be set to the actual function not not a string wrapped in quotes

Comment: @fortunee thanks for the reply, do you mean sth like `myForm.onsubmit=()=>{return foo()};`? It doesnt seem to work...

Comment: Check out my answer below @SugarDrink

Answer (score 2):

The `onsubmit` should be set to the actual function not a string wrapped in quotes

Consider changing this

```js
myForm.onsubmit="return foo()";
```

To this

```js
myForm.onsubmit=foo;
```

Comment: Specifically a _reference_ to the function is assigned to the listener not the result of _calling_ the function.

Answer (score 0):

The `onsubmit` function is supposed to be a `function`, not a `string`.

If you set it as a `string`, it won't work properly.

---

To fix it, simply set it as a function, as below.

```js
myForm.onsubmit = foo;
```

Make sure to not add parentheses (otherwise you will be calling it, and it won't work).

---

You can also try the `addEventListener` function, like so.

```js
myForm.addEventListener("submit", foo);
```

It does the same thing as `onsubmit`, but with a different syntax.